# intellij cant resolve some javafx classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am trying to install JavaFX in IntelliJ. I have included the JavaFX SDK in IntelliJ via Project Structures > Modules > Dependencies. Some classes seem to be resolved, others are not. See screenshot.

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloFX extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello JavaFX!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Hello JavaFX!");
        btn.setOnAction( (event) -> Platform.exit() );
        Pane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root , 300 , 150));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

With the command line commands
`javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX.java`
and
`java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX`
I could compile and start this test class. So the library is installed correctly.

IntelliJ Version 2020.3.2
Java SDK 15
JavaFX (tested with 11 and 15. Same problem)

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is with the not resolving classes?

Comment: no screenshots of text please

Comment: @kleopatra The code is irrelevant because, as I said, it works when I compile and run it from the console.

Comment: @Abra `javafx.scene.Scene` was imported correctly, `javafx.scene.control.Button` and `javafx.stage.Stage` was not.

Comment: Class `javafx.scene.Scene` is in the same module and the same JAR file as class `javafx.stage.Stage`. I don't understand how only one of them is successfully resolved. Your initial screen capture showed the error _Cannot resolve symbol 'Stage'_ I don't know what you mean by _imported correctly_. If there is no error for class `javafx.scene.Scene` then that means that it was successfully resolved by IntelliJ. Maybe you have another class named `Stage` in a different package?

Comment: be precise please: make sure the symptoms of a problem you describe are _exact_ (as @Abra already noted the screenshot controdicted your description) - looks like for some reason your intelli setup doesn't see the graphics module

Comment: You may try to run ""File | Invalidate Caches"

Answer (score 0):

The javafx.fxml modules appears to be missing from the command line above. See below taken from the supplied link.

4. Add VM options

To solve the issue, click on Run -> Edit Configurations... and add these VM options:

--module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-java

Comment: Module javafx.fxml is not needed for the example provided in the question